Box shadow issues in flatlist
I am new to react native and i have a an array of products in my react native expo project for which i am using the Flatlist to render them on screen. i am facing issue where the box shadow is not proper. if i use mapping everything regarding box shadow is perfect but when i use flatlist, there seems to be shadow visible outside the radius of card.
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={styles.card}>
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        marginVertical: 11,
        paddingRight: 14,
        paddingVertical: 13.47,
        gap: 8,
      }}
    >
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text>{item.description}</Text>
      <View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Text>Price- </Text>
          <Text>{item.price}</Text>
          <Text> / Kg</Text>
        </View>
        <Pressable>
          <Text>Add</Text>
        </Pressable>`your text`
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
);

<FlatList
  data={products}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={<View style={{ height: 16 }} />}
/>;

const styles = {
  card: {
    borderRadius: 16,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 4,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.15,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
};

Notice that there is extra shadow on bottom right of cards and the last card has minimal effect o the bottom

probably you paddingRight: 14, line is causing this issue, I cannot reproduce it in a snack, do you have a expo snack to pass and check?
